# How to use file_put_contents() for part of the php file

Tags: php, html

I'm using **PHP and html** in order to develop a simple mechanism that creates reports and send them by Email.
I use the function `file_put_contents()` and the function `ob_get_contents()` as a parameter in order to create an html file which I use to send by the mail.
I realized that if I use `ob_get_contents()` without using `ob_start()` it simply takes all the file and put it to an html file. This is not good for me since I want only parts of the file to be in the generated html. To be more clear my code looks something like this:

```
<html and php code I want to include in my html file>
.
.
<html and php code I don't want to include in my html file>
.
.
<html and php code I want to include in my html file>
.
.
<html and php code I don't want to include in my html file>
.
.
.

file_put_contents('report.html', ob_get_contents());
$message = file_get_contents('report.html');
mail($to, $subject, $message, $Headers);
```

So how do I choose only the parts I want to be included in report.html?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you just "compose" your html by doing 

**$html** = '<html...'; PHP code you don't want to include; **$html** .= '<some other html> + PHP code not executed';

Comment: Or you can make multiple PHP files containing small parts of your large HTML. This way you get to load exactly what files you want. This is more or less the same approach as Kei, except much cleaner and no inline HTML

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it unnecessarily difficult, you don't need external files to generate your report. Take a look at this:

```
<?php
$report = '';

// ...
// Code not included in your report
// ...

ob_start();
// ...
// HTML and PHP code you want in your report
// ...
$report .= ob_get_clean();

// ...
// Code not included in your report
// ...

ob_start();
// ...
// HTML and PHP code you want in your report
// ...
$report .= ob_get_clean();

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $report, $headers);
?>
```

**EDIT:** Regarding to OP's comment.

What you need is `ob_get_flush()` instead of `ob_get_clean()`. Both return the buffer contents as a string, but the first one dumps it to the script output while the second one empties the buffer instead.

Comment: This is a good solution and it worked for me. The problem is that I also present the php file in my GUI (I present the whole php file and send by email only a part). When I use this format, it hides all the contents of the file and I can only see it by Email. Is there a way to write to the buffer but also to the screen? (I hope my question is clear)

Answer (score 0):

***May or May not Help***

---

I always handle this the same way I load pages when using vanila PHP, with a snippet! The following is one I've kept around forever and used. It has 2 possible primary functions. One is to *load* a *view* (html page), the other is to get a page of html as a string for such things as inclusion in an **email body**.

For example:

```
//  will load a page into the clients browser
//    note the page location would indicate it will get the file "index.html" from "$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/views/'"
loadView('/views/index.html');

//  or, as would be more helpful to you
$msgHTML = loadView('/views/index.html', NULL, TRUE);
```

The **`TRUE`** param simply tells the function to only return a string and not echo anything to a client.

The **`NULL`** param you see there is for an array of data to be passed through. For instance, say you have an html page with a table you want populated for a database call. You would simply make your call, place your return in an array and then add to page.

```
$arr = array( 'key' => 'value' );
$msgHTML = loadView('/views/index.html', $arr, TRUE);

//  then in the index.html
<div><?= $key; ?></div>
```

This makes it very easy to build anything HTML you need for an Email.

*Snippet*

---

```
if (!function_exists('loadView')) {
    function loadView($file, $data=NULL, $get=FALSE) {
        if (!empty($data)) extract($data);
        ob_start();
        if (is_file($file)) include($file);
        $return = ob_get_clean();
        if (!$get) echo($return);
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Thus you could do something like:

```
$htmlFirst = loadView('report.html', NULL, TRUE);
$msgFirst = 'Some message string here';
$htmlSecond = loadView('report2.html', NULL, TRUE);
$msgSecond = 'Some message string here';

$body = $htmlFirst . $msgFirst . $htmlSecond . $msgSecond;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $Headers);
```